# Xcode 4.3.1 doxygen comment generation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm currently using the lastest version of xCode and I'd like to be able to do this http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=9u1mrVTRt4w#t=98s as I could in xCode 3.

Can anyone help with possible solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 4 doesn't have the Scripts menu which was built into older Xcode versions. There is a workaround however which leverages Services built into OSX to achieve the same behaviour. In order to add the Doxygen script, there is a step by step guide and the Doxygen.rb script available at this blog post: [Doxygen Shortcuts In Xcode4](http://www.brokenrul.es/blog/?p=761#.T856wD5YtoA)

Comment: I'm out of the office but will try first thing tomorrow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll have to edit the parsing a little but this works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Duck Rowing has a very nice macro cmd-shift-D to generate a template based on the code selected.

Learn more at http://www.duckrowing.com/2011/05/14/using-the-doxygen-helper-in-xcode-4/